# C# Streamline memory reading of multi-pointer

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, readprocessmemory

I have made a method that will read a multi-pointer by providing the wanted offsets + the start adress. (Code below). To summarize, Im trying to streamline this method and below I will explain my problem.

I have been strugling around with the conversion. The parameter is an IntPtr and the output of a read adress is an byte array, my first idea was: "Convert Byte array to IntPtr, reprocess it and finally convert the last read adress into a int32 (since the last adress is not a pointer it will never be read so converting here to Int32 should be allright)",

However that did not give a nice result. So currently Im stuck with the solution of converting Byte array to Int32, then Int32 to IntPtr. People do say that the bitconverter is a bad approach because it might cause issues on 64-bit platforms and I do also believe there is an approach that may give a better performence (since Im converting an object 2 times).

Finally if anyone think it would be possible to make a similar function in C++ and then P/Invoke it in C# (I guess it would be more efficient that way?) please tell me. (Im trying to adapt my programming knowledges. And find combination of languages very interesting)

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "ReadProcessMemory")]
public static extern Int32 ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
[In, Out] byte[] buffer, Int32 sizeout, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

public Int32 ReadBytes(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Address, int[] Offsets, int BytesToRead = 4)
{
    IntPtr ptrBytesRead;
    byte[] value = new byte[BytesToRead];

    ReadProcessMemory(Handle, Address, value, BytesToRead, out ptrBytesRead);

    //Read Offsets
    for (int i = 0; i < Offsets.Length; i++)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(Handle, 
        new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt32(value, 0) + Offsets[i]), 
        value, 
        BytesToRead, 
        out ptrBytesRead);
    }

    return BitConverter.ToInt32(value, 0);
}
```

Any ideas to streamline this method would be very well appreciated! Thanks on advance!

Comment: Any more specific question than "improve this"? Also, ReadProcessMemory will be by far the slowest part. All your "conversions" will not matter for perf.

Comment: That is certainly true! Thanks alot for the reply!
No I dont think so. Atleast not for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @usr stated, the performance of the code will be entirely dominated by the calls to `ReadProcessMemory`. You should not expect to improve the performance from its current level.

However, you can make the code much easier to read by avoiding byte arrays and `BitConverter`. Like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int ReadProcessMemory(
    IntPtr hProcess, 
    IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
    out IntPtr lpBuffer, 
    IntPtr nSize, 
    out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead
);

private static IntPtr ReadProcessPointer(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr Address)
{
    IntPtr result;
    IntPtr NumberOfBytesRead;
    if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, Address, out result, (IntPtr)IntPtr.Size, out NumberOfBytesRead) == 0)
        throw new Win32Exception();
    return result;
}

public static IntPtr FollowPointers(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr Address, int[] Offsets)
{
    IntPtr ptr = ReadProcessPointer(hProcess, Address);
    for (int i = 0; i < Offsets.Length; i++)
        ptr = ReadProcessPointer(hProcess, ptr + Offsets[i]);
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Allright then! It´s a matter of reading multiple bytes at a time and then parse it to improve performence once I want to fetch multiple data from nearby addresses then!